# How php array will move to one dimension from two dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, string, implode

Original array

```
Array ( [1147183647] => 3 [2147483242] => 1 )
```

expected out put

```
Array (1147183647,1147183647,1147183647,2147483242)
```

how can i expand array key base on their value

Comment: [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/array_keys).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

slightly sexier than those using 2 loops is to use the built in `array_fill` function

```
<?php
$array = array(1147183647 => 3, 2147483242 => 1);

$new=array();
foreach ($array as $key=>$var){
$new= array_merge($new,array_fill(0,$var,$key));
}

print_r($new);
```

demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/NTcDhC

Comment: may array is save in session, so i do it like this..
 it return like this to me but it was return like:
 
Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 )

Comment: Hi buddy, can you please check out [this room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82943/room-for-stack-and-dagon) for 5min ? I asked a question about one file `.php.bak` in a simple MVC. only you was who downloaded it and gave me a good answer. Now I have a new question and I think just *you* can help me. waiting for you ...

Answer (score 1):

Loop over each key value pair and add the key to the output array for the value number of repitions:

```
$output = array();
$arr = array(1147183647 => 3, 2147483242 => 1);
foreach($arr as $v => $rep) {
  for($i = 0; $i < $rep; $i++) {
    $output[] = $v;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple snippet.

```
<?php

//initialize array
$array = array(
    "1147183647" => 3, "2147483242" => 1
    ); 

//new array to hold the values
$new =array();

foreach($array as $k=>$v){

    //echo $k."-".$v."<br>";
    for($i=0; $i<$v; $i++){
        $new[] = $k;
    }

}

//check the output
print_r($new);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$array = array(1147183647 => 3, 2147483242 => 1);

    $result=array();
    foreach ($array as $key=>$var){
        $result= array_merge($result,array_fill(0,$var,$key));
    }


    var_dump($result);
```